# How to add .env file

Tags: environment-variables, gedit, clone

I run Ubuntu terminal via windows (installed it via windows insider program)
I joined this company as intern and they have a website that they are working on. I was given certain steps to follow, so I can run the app locally. I have installed Node.js and Yarn, and I cloned the GitHub link. In addition, I installed dependencies using `yarn install`.

The next step is to add .env file, and I do not know how to that in ubuntu. I have tried `sudo -H gedit /etc/environment`

but I get this:

`sudo: gedit: command not found`

I do not know if this is even the same thing. I might be looking the wrong way, but hopefully I will find my answer here.

Comment: gedit is the Gnome text editor. It isn't present unless the Gnome desktop environment is installed and it isn't in a CLI only WSL distro. You should perhaps use `sudoedit` instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try one of the terminal-based text editors.

- Nano  (`sudo nano /path/to/file`)
- Vim   (`sudo vim /path/to/file`)

Your favorite search engine will happily show you many tutorials on how to use either editor. Both take a couple minutes to learn (especially how to save your work and exit!)

The ability to edit files using a terminal is spectacularly useful, and easily worth the few minutes invested to learn. For many of us, it's an *essential* job skill.